# Want to buy Honda Odyssey van

Tags: honda, old-cars

I live in OC, Ca. My long term goal is to buy a good used Honda Odyssey family van. please let me know how do I do it. I am on a low budget and looking to get good bang for the buck. I have never bought a used car before. What are the details and how do you go about doing it.

Comment: Welcome to the site: you should refer to our FAQ (http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) for some guidance on appropriate question topics.  In this case, we'd be a better community to ask how to fix a van rather than how to purchase one.

Comment: [This question](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/what-to-check-when-buying-a-used-car) may give you some guidance

Answer (score 1):

Go to a mechanic you trust.Explain that you are looking for a used car and what would they charge to put it on the lift and check it out for you,time frame involved,advance notice etc.Do some research on line on the vehicles you are interested in.Check what the sale prices are like in your area.Find a vehicle and have your mechanic check it.If the seller is unwilling to allow this walk away quickly and don't look back.Once you have the mechanics report figure the cost of any repairs into the purchase price.Just because something is found doesn't mean it isn't a good deal.It is mearly a bargaining point for the purchase aggrement.