# What are the main things to be identified want to buy a USED car?

Tags: maintenance, old-cars

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to check when buying a used car?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/what-to-check-when-buying-a-used-car)

I want to buy a used car. Nobody can't gives me the clear idea about that. Because someone said manufacturing year is the main one. You don't want to buy a more than 5 year from the manufacturing .At the same time another guy tell me some cars aren't frequently used (daily uses). So it would affect the engine life but they were used the 25k kilometers like that. So what should i do ? whenever i want to buy a used car ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantees with used cars, but you're mostly looking for:

- Appropriate miles for the years.  Too few miles will likely mean the car wasn't used often enough (some parts do not like sitting unused).  Lots of miles and there will be suspension wear that's hard to see (although, it can be a good sign for the engine as long trips are MUCH easier on an engine than city driving).  10,000-15,000 miles a year is considered normal for cars in the USA.
- Rust.  Look carefully under the wheel arches and on the bottom of the doors.  Check the bottom of the car as well.  Some surface rust is expected under a car of age, but look for weak spots/holes.
- Is the car straight or is it crooked?  Should drive straight and body should look straight.
- Receipts.  It's not necessarily bad if someone doesn't have them (I don't keep mine, and I'm obsessive about maintenance!), but if someone DOES have all the maintenance receipts you can check and see how good they were about keeping up on routine maintenance, as well as any problems that might have been happening.