# Buy a new car or old car

Tags: car, old-cars

I had recently started learning a four wheeler (Maruti ALTO) from driving school. Its some week course.

After that should i buy a new car (New ALTO K10 or say SWIFT) or buy a old one as i might be learning and might end up ruining new car, its clutch plates etc.

I had a plan to buy a new car as its financing is easier and less chance of breaking down unlike old car.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are numerous pros and cons for a new car or a used car, and we try to stick to factual, answerable questions.  Any responses you get will be primarily opinion based.

Comment: @JPhi1618 But even then some advice will be beneficial for a guy who had just started learning to buy a new one or not, thanks!

Comment: @Moons Probably going to see the question closed. Advice: Buy a very cheap, average, popular and easy to get rid of car. Get some experience, then decide on your own what you want to do.

Comment: This related question might help you understand what you could be getting into with a used car: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/what-to-check-when-buying-a-used-car

Comment: I wouldn't touch any vehicle made after 1969 with a 10 foot pole!

Comment: Please join us in the chat: lots of us will be happy to discuss options.

Answer (score 3):

How used are we talking here? For me, I always take the price and divide by miles available. I like to always make that number 100,000 miles before major maintenance is required. For instance, if I bought a $20,000 car new, I would divide $ into miles. Therefore, it would be $0.20/mile at 100,000 miles. So if a car has 70,000 miles and costs $10,000, it would be $0.33/mile for 30,000 miles. Usually at 100,000 you will be looking at timing belt, water pump, tensioner, tune up, suspension, etc, etc. That is why I use that mile number. I hope this helps.

Comment: This is confusing and doesn't answer the question of "new car or old car".  How does this per-mile price figure in to a buying decision?