# Opinion on buying a Lancer A17++ vehicle

Tags: maintenance, old-cars, lancer, rebuild

I guess this would be an ideal place to ask this question! If not, please direct me to a suitable forum. :) So my question is, I'm going to buy my first car and, ever since I was a kid I fell in love with the 1980 Mitsubishi lancer Ex ( Models go as A172A, A173A, A175A ). The A175A is a turbo and that model is not available where I live. We only have A172/3 models. So I'm finally able to buy one of these beauties. I would like to know answers to the following questions.

```
1. what would it take to maintain such a car. 
2. what should I have to check before buying it
3. What thoughts you car experts have to say
```

Please guide me so that I could get my dream car.... :)

Comment: You might want to be more specific about the maintenance part of your question. Are you looking for things specific to this car, or any car. I suspect the things specific to just the Lancer will be a very short list. Probably none. And the question of what things ever need to be maintained on a car is really too broad for this forum. But lets see if there are some specifics that folks can contribute. There are a lot of really knowledgeable folks in here. And thank you for your contribution to the site!

Comment: Some very good general info on buying a used car here:  http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/what-to-check-when-buying-a-used-car?lq=1

Comment: I'm looking for this specific to this car..  And yeah i feel like my question is on the broad side but, to narrow it down i have little idea on car mechanics. To be honest this would be my first car.. So any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: goto the chat room and talk to some folks in there.  They will help guide you on some of the subject matter.  Since this is a buying question......it get's the close hammer.     Just go here though.     http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop